# index.php navigation

Tags: php, navigation

I am working on a site as an intern. The site that i am working with is called www.erikzandstra.nl (its dutch) Currently, I am working on the blog page. On the blog page, I wanted to add some php code to get navigation buttons to go to the next and previous posts. I searched through internet and could not find any code that worked. I cant program with php but i kinda do understand it.
What i need is some (php)code that makes 2 buttons to go to previous and next posts.
Here is the code i currently use:

```
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article">

                    <header>

                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'wpbs-featured' ); ?></a>

                        <div class="page-header"><h1 class="h2"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1></div>

                        <p class="meta"><?php _e("Posted", "wpbootstrap"); ?> <time datetime="<?php echo the_time('Y-m-j'); ?>" pubdate><?php echo get_the_date('F jS, Y', '','', FALSE); ?></time> <?php _e("by", "wpbootstrap"); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> <span class="amp">&</span> <?php _e("filed under", "wpbootstrap"); ?> <?php the_category(', '); ?>.</p>

                    </header> <!-- end article header -->

                    <section class="post_content clearfix">
                        <?php the_content( __("Read more &raquo;","wpbootstrap") ); ?>
                    </section> <!-- end article section -->

                    <footer>

                        <p class="tags"><?php the_tags('<span class="tags-title">' . __("Tags","wpbootstrap") . ':</span> ', ' ', ''); ?></p>

                    </footer> <!-- end article footer -->

                </article> <!-- end article -->

                <?php endwhile; ?>  

                <?php if (function_exists('wp_bootstrap_page_navi')) { // if expirimental feature is active ?>

                    <?php wp_bootstrap_page_navi(); // use the page navi function ?>

                <?php } else { // if it is disabled, display regular wp prev & next links ?>
                    <nav class="wp-prev-next">
                        <ul class="pager">
                            <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next post >'); ?>

                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                <?php } ?>      

                <?php else : ?>

                <article id="post-not-found">
                    <header>
                        <h1><?php _e("Not Found", "wpbootstrap"); ?></h1>
                    </header>
                    <section class="post_content">
                        <p><?php _e("Sorry, but the requested resource was not found on this site.", "wpbootstrap"); ?></p>
                    </section>
                    <footer>
                    </footer>
                </article>

                <?php endif; ?>

            </div> <!-- end #main -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); // sidebar 1 ?>

        </div> <!-- end #content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use wp_link_pages function, it's was built for that purpose.

```
$defaults = array(
    'before'           => '<p>' . __( 'Pages:' ),
    'after'            => '</p>',
    'link_before'      => '',
    'link_after'       => '',
    'next_or_number'   => 'number',
    'separator'        => ' ',
    'nextpagelink'     => __( 'Next page' ),
    'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous page' ),
    'pagelink'         => '%',
    'echo'             => 1
);

    wp_link_pages( $defaults );
```

You can refer to the codex page to learn more how to use each parameter : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages